# Difference between these two method of creating array?

Tags: arrays, vb.net

What is the difference between following these two methods of creating arrays in VB.net, do they work similarly ?   Which one to prefer and under what conditions ?

1st Method :

```
Dim testarray(2) as String 
testarray(0) = "string1"
testarray(1) = "string2"
testarray(2) = "string3"
```

2nd Method :

System.Array class provides a shared method named CreateInstance, which creates a new instance of the System.Array class.

```
Dim   testarray as Array = Array.CreateInstance(GetType(String),2)
testarray.SetValue(CStr("Test string"),0)
```

Thanks

Comment: Try them both and see for yourself?

Comment: Don't know, why this question got down voted ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first one returns an array of `string` as array of `string`. The second one returns an array of `string` as non-generic `Array` class object.

Using the second one you're loosing compile time type safety and you can expose your code to boxing/unboxing operations. That's because `SetValue` method takes `object` instead of proper (`string` in your example) type instance.

You should definitely use the first one.

Comment: Thanks !  I'm new to vb.net and your reply was really helpful.

Answer (score 1):

I'd use

```
    Dim ta() As String = New String() {"1", "2", "3"}
```

Comment: +1. You can also write it as `Dim ta() As String = {"1", "2", "3"}`.

Comment: Yes you can, though I am not sure what version of .Net this was introduced in.

Comment: Works in VS 2008 and VS 2010, .NET 2.0 and up. Cannot check older than that.

Comment: I think it's called Option Infer. Available since VS 2008. Links: [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384665.aspx). [about.com](http://visualbasic.about.com/od/usingvbnet/a/linqlangopinf.htm).

Comment: `Dim ta As String() = {"1", "2", "3"}` is preferred  Link: [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/y13tek7e.aspx)